# Where is the full Yammer API documentation

Tags: api, yammer

The Yammer API is partially documented here.

- https://developer.yammer.com/v1.0/docs/rest-api-rate-limits

I expect to find this endpoint documented

- https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/groups.json

but it not documented.

I found it in this post

- [Yammer API - List of groups for each user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25150035/yammer-api-list-of-groups-for-each-user?rq=1)

And it does work.

I assume that there are other useful endpoints as well.

Can someone point me to more complete documentation. Or is it possible to query the API for a list of endpoints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first link you list is in fact the full documentation. Groups.json is a working endpoint, but not a *documented* one. This means that Yammer does not promise to support this endpoint, and may decide to change it at any point, possibly breaking any code that relies upon it.

You can find lots of undocumented endpoints by running a toll such as Fiddler against the Yammer web interface, and lots of developers, myself included, develop solutions against these endpoints. We just have to remember, and make sure our clients understand, the implications of developing with these APIs.